# Is it possible for a firewall to block only audio in webrtc?

Tags: javascript, network-programming, webrtc

At work we have a webrtc call feature in our aplication.

All works well besides a problem we have with one of our clients.

We are able to establish the connection between the peers but for some reason, usualy when there is something afecting the connection, the peer that had the connection problem simply stops sending audio data. The video stream continue to work just fine, only the audio is afected.

We have Stun/Turn servers and the peers are using them, we had to ask for the client IT department to open exceptions on the firewall for that.

My guess is that something is "cutting" the audio stream after some time, is that even possible?

I am out of ideas how to resolve the issue. The iceConnectionState remains connected when the issue happens so I can't even rely on that to try to reconnect or renegotiate the icecandidates.

Thanks for any light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the audio and video tracks are sent over the same peer connection, it's very unlikely that the Firewall will block only audio RTP packets.

Assuming it's a web app, if your client is using Chrome, you can check chrome://webrtc-internals (during the call) and look at graphs of RTCOutboundRTPAudioStream and compare to RTCOutboundRTPVideoStream.
If no data (not even headers) are sent and the track stopped completely, you may need to check if something in your application is stopping the audio track, or if the audio track is removed from the peer connection.
Again, assuming it's a web app, you can listen to [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack#events) on the track.
It won't give you the reason, but can allow cross-reference with other events happening on the same time.